# Update UI when another user make actions (php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, user-interface, action

today I've a question; dunno how to call this but I'll try to explain.

I've got a START button, which push the "search" mode below :

[image]

I want, when 2 users are in "search" that the second image appears :
[image]

and when one user click on START it will update picture (green border) which means "I'm ready."

So,

1. How can I match 2 users who are in "search" mode ?
2. How can I update picture when user click on START
   ?

I don't know how to do that; which langage ? which function ? And maybe how can I call this needed ? Just need to be informed :)
Thanks in advance.
NB: I'm using PHP/JS

Comment: This is a pretty big thing to ask. Try researching WebSockets or find some tutorials on how to make your own instant messenger. Basically, you need to learn how to track users on your server and send updates to the client based on that. Much too broad for a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll search on your suggestion.